# SQLITE3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error when creating database

Tags: python, sqlite

I can't seem to be able to see for myself, what when wrong in this line of codes, have been staring at it for the last 20 min but I can't seem to figure anything out.

here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\usera\PycharmProjects\itptesting_2\itptesting\init_db.py", line 7, in <module>
    connection.executescript(f.read()),
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error
```

and the fullcode:

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('database.db')


with open('schema.sql') as f:
    connection.executescript(f.read())

cur = connection.cursor()

cur.execute("INSERT INTO posts (title, content) VALUES (?, ?)",
            ('First Post', 'Content for the first post')
            )

cur.execute("INSERT INTO posts (title, content) VALUES (?, ?)",
            ('Second Post', 'Content for the second post')
            )

cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (fullname, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
            ('UserA', 'user@demo.com', 'asdfghjkl')
            )

cur.execute("INSERT INTO entries (stockname, partnum, company, quantity, uom, remarks) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
            ('Beer','Albee0001','RES','24','BTL','new stock for promotions ')
            )

connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

and schema.sql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS posts;

CREATE TABLE posts (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    created_timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    content TEXT NOT NULL
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS signup;

CREATE TABLE users (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    fullname TEXT NOT NULL,
    email TEXT NOT NULL,
    password TEXT NOT NULL
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS entries;

CREATE TABLE entries (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    stockname TEXT NOT NULL,
    partnum TEXT NOT NULL,
    company TEXT NOT NULL,
    quantity INTEGER NOT NULL,
    uom TEXT NOT NULL,
    date_recorded NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    remarks TEXT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES users(id),
);
```

I had tried deleting the database.db file and regenerating it by run init_db.py but it still gave me the same error. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of problems, this is the correct syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE entries (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    stockname TEXT NOT NULL,
    partnum TEXT NOT NULL,
    company TEXT NOT NULL,
    quantity INTEGER NOT NULL,
    uom TEXT NOT NULL,
    date_recorded DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
    remarks TEXT,
    FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```